# Homebrew installation hanging on "Receiving objects"

Tags: homebrew

I'm attempting to install homebrew through the advised command line...

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

When the installation gets to "Receiving objects" the installation simply hangs...

```
==> Downloading and Installing Homebrew...
remote: Counting objects: 126495, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (58957/58957), done.
Receiving objects:  33% (41744/126495), 8.74 MiB | 598.00 KiB/s
```

The above is the second attempt at installing Homebrew. The first attempt got to 56% before hanging.

After aborting the installation I'm getting this...

```
^CFailed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this script hang twice. I waited overnight, as suggested by TATN, but this did not work in my case. However, when I restarted my computer the script ran quickly to successful completion.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it clearly tells you that the installation has failed, just give it sometime. Maybe your computer was slow or something was delaying it. I have seen it taken from 10m (on a stabled computer) to overnight (on a slow computer).